# Plotting from a for loop

Tags: r

```
 set.seed(666999)
  PLOT <- function(n){
    n_samples<-10
    #Creating matrix to store generated data
    data_matrix<-matrix(ncol =n_samples, nrow= n)
    for(j in 1:n_samples){
      #Generating 10 standard normal samples of size n
      data_matrix[ , j]<-rnorm(n=n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    }
    
    for(k in 1:n_samples){
      sam_20<-data_matrix[ , k] 
      # extracting each of the kth samples
      #Ploting
       Q_Qplot<-qqnorm( sam_20 )
      Q_QplotL<-qqline( sam_20 )
      #Q_Qplot<-gg_qqplot(sam_20, ylab="Sample Quantiles", 
                      #xlab = "Theoritical Quantiles", 
                      #main= bquote("Q-Q plot for sample size of "
                         #          ~ n  == ~ .(n)))#quantile-quantile plot
    }
   # return(n)
    #return(Q_Qplot)
    #return(Q_QplotL)
  }
#layout_matrix_1 <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 5)                 # Define position matrix
#layout(layout_matrix_1)
PLOT(100)
PLOT(50)
PLOT(20)
PLOT(10)
```

For each sample size, I am generating ten plots. I want the layout for each of my 10 plots to fit well on a page with reasonable height and width. For some reason, I can't get it to work the way I wanted. I need some assistance perhaps with ggplot2 which has a better aesthetic view. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)


#Values to simulate
sample_size <- c(10,20,50,100)
sample_num <- 1:10

#Create data.frame
expand_grid(sample_size,sample_num) %>% 
  #Map values to simulate cenarios
  mutate(y = map(sample_size,sim_data)) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(y)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sample = y))+
  #qqplot
  stat_qq()+
  #qqline with color blue
  stat_qq_line(col = "blue")+
  #facet sample_size x sample_num
  facet_grid(cols = vars(sample_size),rows = vars(sample_num))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Vinicius but I felt like you answered my question partially.

Comment: I need to obtain 10 plots for each case because I generated 10 samples of size n (10, 20, 50, 100). If you could run my original lines of codes, you will realize what I am talking about.

Comment: @Kwame now I see, I made the code simpler, see if this what you want

Comment: Thanks, Vinícius, this one helps.